# Azure server got error "system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full Ip"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, azure-sql-database

i have hosted my project on azure server of Asp.net MVC, and i have used azure sql, its work fine, but number of times while performing any operation , i.e. when fire calls from controller it gives error like,

"An operation on a socket could not be performed because the system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full Ip"

and after few minutes  its starts to work fine,
can anyone tell me why this error is throwing or is there any solution for this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most probably client side issue (ASP.Net app side). This could happen if you do A LOT of simultaneous socket connections or do not dispose connections properly. Please double check your application and make sure that:

1. You properly close all database connections (use using() or call Dispose()).
2. You properly close any other socket connection (if any).

If your code is fine, you can try to use [Transient Fault Handling App Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh680934%28v=PandP.50%29.aspx). It won't solve the issue itself but could help your app to workaround it.

Comment: I got the same erorr for my service bus question is posted here pls help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64152317/azure-service-bus-deadletter-queue-message-unable-to-stay-in-deadletter-for-long