# "An operation on a socket could not be performed" with HttpClientFactory

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, httpclient, httpclientfactory

I'm having a long-running triggered webjob on Azure, that uses multiple typed http clients to access remote services. The amount of requests per launch goes as far as millions, but after ~30k I'm getting the following exception:

> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An operation on a socket could not be performed because the system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full.

I'm using the Microsoft.Extensions.Http 2.2.0 to inject typed http clients with Http Client Factory.

By now I've tried running this locally with fake data and receiver; and monitor the connections with

> netstat -b

...and

> var ipProperties = IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties();
>
> var tcpConnections = ipProperties.GetActiveTcpConnections();

...but I couldn't reproduce the error; and amount of connections stayed around the same the whole time. It makes me think something other than connection limit causes this error.

I'd try the same in Azure; but this does not seem to work as Kudu doesn't allow netstat or similar command.

The clients are added to services like this:

```cs
collection.AddHttpClient<ISenderClient, SenderClient>()
                .ConfigureHttpClient((provider, client) =>
            {
                 //... configuring base url and headers
            })
                .SetHandlerLifetime(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
```

Then injected into SenderClient:

```cs
public sealed class SenderClient : ISenderClient, IDisposable
    {
        private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

        public SenderClient(HttpClient httpClient)
        {
            _httpClient = httpClient ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(httpClient));
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _httpClient?.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

SenderClient itself is retrieved from service provider:

```cs
_client = _provider.GetService<ISenderClient>();
```

...and later used in Parallel.ForEach loop to distribute http requests:

```cs
Parallel.ForEach(batches, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 8 }, (batch, state, i) =>
            {
                using (var scope = _provider.CreateScope())
                {
                    var provider = scope.ServiceProvider;

                    //... dto mapping

                    var response = _client.SendAsync<Request, Response>(request).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                 }
             }
```

where SendAsync is

```cs
public async Task<TResponse> SendAsync<TRequest, TResponse>(TRequest request)
        {
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request);
            using (var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"))
            using (var response = await _client.PostAsync(_url, content))
            {
                var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TResponse>(responseString);
            }
        }
```

Could anybody please explain what could cause this exception, as I'm having hard times trying to fix this issue for a long time by now..?

EDIT: I believe that my question is not a duplicate of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23211017/azure-server-got-error-system-lacked-sufficient-buffer-space-or-because-a-queue), because I'm using HttpClientFactory rather than handling clients manually. This should take care of managing, refreshing and disposing of connections; and is considered a preferred way of handling http clients.

I should only have one connection of a type at a certain period of time with this approach.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Azure server got error "system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full Ip"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23211017/azure-server-got-error-system-lacked-sufficient-buffer-space-or-because-a-queue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We transferred the job to app service with a superior pricing tier, and it kind of fixed the issue; though I'm not entirely satisfied with this solution.